# How to loop a Coldfusion cfquery in Cfscript?

Tags: loops, coldfusion

I'm trying to loop a query in `cfscript`. I think I have it, but it the query loops into infinity.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in the following:

```
<cfscript>
    // loop single msg
    variables.allRows = current_message.recordcount;
    for ( variables.intRow = 1 ; variables.allRows LTE variables.intRow ; variables.intRow = variables.intRow + 1 ){
        variables.msg_id_viewed = current_message[ "com_msg_id" ][ variables.intRow ];
        variables.msg_app_alias = current_message[ "com_app_alias" ][variables.intRow];
        variables.msg_img_ext = current_message[ "com_img" ][ variables.intRow ];
        }
</cfscript>
```

The query `current_message` returns a single record, so this should loop once only.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have your condition around the wrong way.

It should be:

```
variables.intRow LTE variables.allRows
```

I suspect `current_message` actually has multiple rows.  Did you *actually check*, or did you simply run on the assumption that that's what you're expecting?  Because it looks to me like `variables.allRows LTE variables.intRow` is evaluating to `false`, which suggests `variables.allRows` is greater than one when you first start.

In regards to this:

> The query current_message returns a single record, so this should loop
>   once only.

If there's only one row - and you *know* this to be the case - why are you looping?

That said, what version of ColdFusion are you on?  In CF10 one can loop over a recordset with the for/in construct, thus:

```
for (row in recordset){
    // row is a struct keyed on each column name, the values being the value for that column/row
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using `Coldfusion8`. Why I'm looping over the query? What other way is there to iterate over a query :-)? I only know `cfoutput query=...` but since I'm using cfouput for outputting to the page, I'm always cf-looping when I want to get query results. Then... I'm using CF for a few months only, so, how should I get the query result then (it is one record, cause I*m pulling from message by message_id and user_id)

Comment: "What other way is there to iterate over a query :-)?"  The thing is you don't need to *iterate* over it if there's only one record: just access it directly!  One can *always* access a recordset via the `queryName.columnName[rowIndex]` syntax (as you are in your loop, but you needn't be *in* a loop if you can directly specify the `rowIndex`).  The only benefit using a query loop gives you is that it increments the `rowIndex` for you.  And in the case of `<cfoutput>` and `<cfloop>`, they also expose the current row's columns without the need to specify the index.

Comment: ok. I didn't know the `queryName.columnName[rowIndex]`.... Cool. Thanks a lot. This saves a ton of looping :-)

Comment: Well ya did know about it... you were using it in the code you posted in yer question!  But anyway, glad the pieces clicked together.